# matching row for data obtained from dplyr summarize_each

Tags: r, dplyr

I want know what the Sepal.Length is for the minimum Sepal.Width for each species, but I can't figure out how to get the matching rows for the row that has the minimum Sepal.Width.

```
library(dplyr)
itable <- tbl_df(iris)
#print(itable)
a <- itable %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_each(funs(min(Sepal.Width)))
print(a)
```

Sorry for the basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `summarise_each`, you need to `filter` down to the rows with the minimums (and maybe `select` just `Sepal.Length`, if you like).

```
> iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% filter(Sepal.Width == min(Sepal.Width)) %>% select(Sepal.Length)

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: Species [3]

     Species Sepal.Length
      (fctr)        (dbl)
1     setosa          4.5
2 versicolor          5.0
3  virginica          6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `slice`

```
 iris %>%
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      slice(which.min(Sepal.Width))
```

Or with `top_n`

```
iris %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
     top_n(1, Sepal.Width)
```